# Referencing user object inside model method in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following in my model:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def my_latest_song(self):
        song = Song.objects.filter(genre_id=self.id, author_id=XXXXXXXXX).order_by('-date')
        return song[0];

class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

So with the my_latest_song method I want to obtain for each genre what the latest song is *for the user currently logged in*. Note: I am already making sure that users MUST be logged in to see this, do not worry about this additional validation.

The question is: **how can I pass the user id of the user that is currently logged in onto this model method?** Where the XXXXXXXXXX is listed I have tried:

- author_id=request.user.id
- author_id=user.id
- author=request.user
- author=user

And many similar options. But I'm new to Django and just not sure about how to properly reference this. Nothing is working yet.

Please note: the issue is that I am constantly (in many different views) displaying the latest song for each genre. So that's why I am thinking it makes sense in the model. It's not stored in a database, it's simply retrieved within the model. Please let me know if this is not appropriate.

For instance, on many pages I am showing a list of genres and for each genre the latest song uploaded by that user:

```
Genre   | Last Song
----------------------
Pop     | Song 1
Rock    | Song 33
Classic | Song 32
```

Comment: The short answer — you should not want to do this in model. Seriously, current user is not accessible in the model for some purpose — it's present in another context (request etc), so, normally should be managed in view. It keeps out out of troubles (for example, what should be treated as 'current user', when you update your model's instance in some management command?).

But, if you really want to have current request's user accessible in model context, you could make it via custom middleware, it is possible.

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy is right, there is no way you would get user data within the model layer itself. You could pass it as a parameter. Or do it the other way round - make `my_latest_song()` a user's model method (that would be more natural to me) and then pass it the genre id. Middleware seems to be an overkill - although technically possible, you probably want your middleware stack as thin as possible due to performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
...
def my_latest_song(self, user_id):
    song = Song.objects.filter(genre_id=self.id, author=User.objects.get(pk=user_id)).order_by('date')
    return song[0];
...
```

You will not be able to use request.user.id or any other request value in that method, as the model does not actually use requests. That usually is done by a form.

Comment: I tried user_id but somehow I need to define this, I haven't yet been able to figure out how to do so in the model, e.g. what classes to import to make this work.

Comment: I updated my answer. Instead of filtering on author_id, use author (the property named on Song class) and filter by an AUTH_USER_MODEL. This will depend on your code so it might not be exactly User.objects.get(pk=user_id), but it have to be the same type as the model property.

Comment: Thanks but what I am mostly wondering about is in what "variable" does Django store my user ID? If I use Django's built-in authorization system, what is the recommended way to get the currently logged-in user details? That's what I struggle with most...

Answer (score -1):

You should not be making this query in your model. It is much better to make the query in `views.py` whenever you need the information.

Below is, if I understand correctly, what you would need to do to make this query in the view.

```
def relevant_view(request,genreID_from_url):
    # ... #
    song = Song.objects.filter(author=request.user).filter(genre=genreID_from_url).order_by('-date')[:1]
    # ... #
```

A couple of points:

- I think you would need to pass the genre you are querying for in the URL. Here is a good tutorial for that: http://django-book.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter03.html#your-third-view-dynamic-urls . You could also do it using a form - it depends on the circumstances in which the query needs to be made.
- You need to order by '-date' and not 'date' so that you get the most recent song at the start of the query.
- The [ ] at the end is Django's syntax for limiting a queryset. The above limits it to only the first item of the queryset, as you are attempting to do.

The page in the Django docs for queries is really helpful and clear: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning about this. Do you mind illustrating how I could phrase this query within my view, because I have trouble setting this up.

Comment: This is a strange answer. OP is not saving the latest song in the database, and hasn't asked how to do so, only how to query it. Your answer seems unrelated to what OP is actually doing.

Comment: @user585936 I have edited my answer to address your comment

Comment: @DanielRoseman That was a misunderstanding on my part, thanks for pointing it out to me. I have edited the answer to address this.

Comment: @cbuch1800 Thanks but in this case there is one query for each genre. Instead, I'm trying to get a list with all genres (say, presented in a table), in which one of the columns shows the most recent songs.

Comment: @cbuch1800 I have added more details to the original question for illustration